# Finding the correct button the user selected in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that looks like this 
[image]

The problem I am having is trying to figure out which radio button on the DCP column is  pressed. My Javascript looks like this:

```
function disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioButton) {
    $('#payer-contract-global-table .clone-target').each(function (i)  {
        var radioName = 'radio' + '-c' + i;
        if (selectedRadioButton != radioName) {
            $('#' + radioName).prop("checked", false);
        }
        else
            $('#' + radioName).prop("checked", true);


    });
}

$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(e){
    var selectedRadioName = $(this).attr('name');
    disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioName);
});
```

I thought `$('#' + radioName).prop("checked", false);` would set the attribute to false and I could find out what the user selected. But when I inspect all I find is this:

```
<input checked="" class="radio-button" id="radio-c2" name="radio-c2" type="radio" currency-format="true" u-index="1">
```

I thought I would see something like checked = "false" or checked = "true", but this checked is the same for all of the buttons. Any idea how I can set a value to know which button is selected?

Here is my HAML:

```
      %input.radio-button{:name => "radio-c#{index}", :type => "radio", :id => "radio-c#{index}", :checked => true }
```

Comment: But don't you already have the selected radio at var selectedRadioName = $(this).attr('name');?

Comment: .clone-target is not the class of the radio button as you reported it is: class="radio-button"

Comment: It seems you're trying to model something that is standard behaviour. Isn't that what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/95nz4j8m/? Or did I geht something wrong?

Comment: It _would_ be standard behavior if all the radio buttons had the same `name="..."` — but it looks like they are `name="radio-c1"` ... `name="radio_c2"` etc, so the radio buttons are _unrelated_ to each other. @JohnSmith — when you're selecting _one_ radio button from a set, they should all have the same _name_.

Comment: Not sure why you are extracted the name attribute when you can use id to figure out which radio button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know: there can only be one checked radio button, and whenever one radio button is checked, the browser's default behaviour is to make the other radio buttons unchecked. You don't have to uncheck anything yourself if the radio buttons each have the same name.

There are simple ways, via jQuery, to obtain what are the checked and unchecked radio buttons.

Two good methods are as follows:

```
$('input[name=example]:checked'); // this finds all checked input elements with name of 'example'
$('input[name=example]').not(':checked'); // this finds all unchecked input elements with name 'example'
```

Here's an example showing how to put that into work.

```js
function displayRadioSelections() {
  var selValues = $('input[name=example]:checked').val();
  $("#selected").text(selValues);
  
  var unselValues = [];
  $('input[name=example]').not(':checked').each(function(i, radio) {
    unselValues.push($(radio).val());
  });
  $("#unselected").text(unselValues.join(', '));    
}

$("div").on("change", "input[name=example]", function() {
  displayRadioSelections();
});
displayRadioSelections();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="1">1</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="2">2</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="3">3</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="4">4</div>
<p>Selected radio: <span id="selected"></span></p>
<p>Unselected radio values: <span id="unselected"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To deselect all the other elements (I used a checkbox in my example but you may adapt to your needs):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:not("#' + this.id + '")').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<input class="radio-button" id="radio-c1" name="radio-c2" type="checkbox" currency-format="true" u-index="1">
<input class="radio-button" id="radio-c2" name="radio-c2" type="checkbox" currency-format="true" u-index="1">
<input class="radio-button" id="radio-c3" name="radio-c2" type="checkbox" currency-format="true" u-index="1">
<input class="radio-button" id="radio-c4" name="radio-c2" type="checkbox" currency-format="true" u-index="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

It will print specific radio button of ID.

HTML:

```
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="1" id='1'>1</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="2" id='2'>2</div> 
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="3" id='3'>3</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="example" value="4" id='4'>4</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

And I see, you are using Rails. Why just not to use rails forms ?

```
<%= f.label :title, "Yes", :value => "true"  %>
<%= f.radio_button :title, true %>
<%= f.label :title, "No", :value => "false" %>
<%= f.radio_button :title, false, :checked => true %>
```

Check Box: It will return 1 or 0.

```
<%= f.label :remember_me do %>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
<% end %>
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/actionpack/3.2.11/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper#radio_button-instance_method